# Heroku CLI HTTP Proxy Error

Tags: heroku, proxy

I am integrating IBM Watson Conversation with Twilio using node.js. For the most part I have been successful. I want to deploy the application on Heroku so it is continually active. I have windows OS. As I am completing the project on my laptop using the school wifi there is a proxy server.

I edited my environment varibles...

Variable Name: http_proxy
Variable Value: HTTPS_PROXY=https://proxy.server.com:port number

It literally looks like that. I have a feeling I actually have to input a port number and proxy address. If so,
**1) How do I find this port number**?
**2) How do I find the proxy address?**

What I currently get when I attempt to Login to Heroku through cmd.exe is...

C:\Users\dnort>heroku login
Enter your Heroku credentials:
Email: dnorton8494@tuskegee.edu
Password: ***********
 ! ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT: Port should be > 0 and < 65536. Received null.

**3) What does "! ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT: Port should be > 0 and < 65536. Received null." mean?**

Comment: This is more of a computer/service configuration question and will probably get more attention at [superuser](https://superuser.com/) or [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/). You might also consider asking your school's IT help desk for the proxy info.

Comment: I guess when working on the local machine you need to start xampp or wamp on windows or lamp on mac. That worked for me!